# Actions of Finite Groups on Trees

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

> Any action of a finite group on a (non-empty) tree has a global fixed point (in the sense that there is a vertex fixed by all group elements or an edge fixed by all group elements).

There is a hint which says we can consider the diameter of the corresponding orbit is minimal. However I don't find the definition of diameter in the book.

Can someone clarify the *diameter*? Or give the details of proof? Thank you.

Comment: If a group is such that whenever it acts on a tree there is a global fixed point then that group is said to have *Property FA*. Note that every group acts on a tree - take a tree with a single parent vertex and children labelled by the group elements. Then $G$ acts on this tree by permuting the children in the natural way. However, there is a global fixed point! Groups which act without such a global fixed point are "interesting", for some value of interesting.

Comment: The diameter of a subset $X$ is usually $\sup_{x,y\in X}d(x,y)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a tree $T_0$; let $T$ denote its barycentric subdvision, that is add the middlepoint of each edge as a vertex. Thus, the action $G \curvearrowright T_0$ has a global fixed point (in the sense you mention) iff the action $G \curvearrowright T$ fixes a vertex.

**Solution 1:** Let $Y \subset T$ be a bounded set. Its radius is defined as $$r_Y= \inf \{ r>0 \mid \exists x, \ Y \subset B(x,r) \}.$$ A point $x \in X$ is a center of $Y$ if $Y \subset B(x,r_Y)$.

A fundamental property is that any bounded set in a tree has a unique center. Therefore, if $Y$ is a bounded orbit (in your case, any orbit works since $G$ is finite), and $x$ is its center, then for all $g \in G$, $g \cdot x$ is the center of $g \cdot Y = Y$ hence $g \cdot x=x$. That is, $x$ is fixed by $G$ (and it is necessarily a vertex of $T$).

In fact, the proof works in any CAT(0) space.

**Solution 2:** Using Bass-Serre theory, and because any HNN extension or nontrivial free amalgamation is infinite, $G$ may be written as a trivial free amalgamation $A \underset{C}{\ast} B$, ie. $G=A$ or $B$. Because $A$ and $B$ are identified with the stabilizer of some vertex, we deduce that $G$ fixes a vertex.

Comment: I am not convinced by Solution 2. At the very least, you need to point out that $G$ does not map on to $\mathbb{Z}$ (see the equivalent definition of Property FA). But +1 anyway!

Comment: I think that $G$ has no quotient isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ because it is not a HNN extension: if $G/N \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and $t \in G$ is sent on a generator by $G \to G/N$, then $G$ seems to be a HNN extension of $N$ with respect to $\varphi : x \mapsto txt^{-1} \in \mathrm{Aut}(N)$.

Comment: By the way, it is a classical result that a group is splittable iff it acts (without inversion) on a tree without global fixed points.

Comment: Could you give a reference to *the fundamental property*?

Comment: @gaoxinge: A proof for CAT(0) spaces can be found in Bridson and Haefliger's book, *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature*, proposition II.2.7.

Comment: @Serios No, your quoting of the classical result is not quite. That is what I mean by the equivalent definition of property FA.

Comment: The issue is the linear tree. Any group which maps onto $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on it without any fixed points, but such groups do not necessarily split in a non-trivial way. For example, the infinite cyclic group is the HNN extension of the trivial group. Which is trivial!

Comment: (Also, the fact serios quotes can be found in Serre's book Trees, which is the fundamental reference for this stuff. Although it is very much pre-CAT(0).)

Comment: I think we only disagree on the vocabulary. For me (and I think it is the usual definition), a group $G$ is said splittable if $G= A \underset{C}{\ast} B$ with $A,B \neq H$ or $G= \underset{C}{\ast} A$. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z} = \underset{\{1\}}{\ast} \{1\}$ is splittable!

Comment: @Serios Gah! I had not meant to give the example of $\mathbb{Z}$! Anyway, I don't think we are just quibbling about definitions. Rather, I am unconvinced that a group has FA if and only if it does not split. Serre states that a finitely generated group has FA if and only if it does not split as an amalgam and does not map onto $\mathbb{Z}$. He does not say "...and is not an HNN-extension". Perhaps Bridson and Haefliger prove more, I don't know. Essentially, what I am saying is "convince me that every group which maps onto $\mathbb{Z}$ splits".

Comment: If $G \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is onto, then $G$ acts naturally on the linear tree $T$ through the action of $\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly, $T/G$ has only one vertex and one edge, and their stabilizers are precisely the kernel $N$ of $G \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. From the associated graph of groups, we see that $G$ splits as $\underset{N}{\ast} N$.

Comment: @Seirios Ah, okay, I understand. I never thought to try to prove it - I think laziness is starting to take over... That said, $N$ is not guaranteed to be finitely generated (for example, in Rips construction or simply taking $G=F_2$). I wonder if a finitely generated group which does not have FA and does not map onto $\mathbb{Z}$ splits as an amalgam $G=A\ast_CB$ where $A$, $B$ (and maybe $C$?) are all finitely generated...

Comment: Sorry for digging up and old post, but why define the barycentric subdivision in Solution 1? Why couldn't you instead look at $T_0$, find a bounded subset, find its center, and conclude the existence of a fixed vertex? Doesn't a fixed vertex of $T$ give you the weaker conclusion that $T_0$ has *either* a fixed vertex or edge?

Answer (score 0):

Any orbit of a vertex is a collection of vertices. As such, it is a subgraph of the given graph and hence is itself a graph. Thus, for this case, my guess is that "diameter" is in the graph theoretic sense. But what would it mean for edges? I'm not sure. In any case, the orbit is itself a metric space and the diameter of a metric space $(X,d)$, is well-known:

$diam(X,d) = \sup_{x,y \in X} d(x,y).$